# SFSafariViewController init method forced to use iOS11 supported version

Tags: ios, xcode, sfsafariviewcontroller, xcode9-beta

With the recent update on Xcode 9 Beta and iOS11 preview, there are some changes to SFSafariViewController `init` methods.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public init(url URL: URL, configuration: SFSafariViewController.Configuration)

@available(iOS, introduced: 9.0, deprecated: 11.0)
public convenience init(url URL: URL, entersReaderIfAvailable: Bool)
```

There is one new `init` method that is supported from iOS11 onwards while the currently available init method will be deprecated by iOS11. The problem is that the current method is not exposed and could not be overwritten. This forces the use of the new `init` method if we want to use the beta to run the existing project. Has anyone found a way to use the existing `init` method in the new Xcode Beta?

Edit: For clarification, this is a snippet of the `init` method in my subclass

```
class BPSafariViewController: SFSafariViewController {
    override init(url URL: URL, entersReaderIfAvailable: Bool) {
        super.init(url: URL, entersReaderIfAvailable: entersReaderIfAvailable)
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.BPUIColor()
        } else {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.BPUIColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possible solution relying on another `convenience` method. Although I cannot use `entersReaderIfAvailable` option, it works for my app for now.

```
convenience init(url URL: URL) {
    self.init(url: URL)
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that while checking the `iOS` version as below.

```
var safariController: SFSafariViewController?
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "your_url")!)
} else {
    safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "")!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
}
```

Comment: Hi Sohil. Thanks for your answer. I am using the init method as an override for a SFSafariViewController subclass.

Comment: @JohnKuan This is the `init` itself. What error are you facing above?

Comment: I am using an existing subclass of SFSafariViewController hence I require the override method available. The problem is this `init` method has been marked for deprecation and I had to use another `init`.

Answer (score 1):

Change deprecated function:

```
super.init(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
```

to:

```
let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
    
super.init(url: url, configuration: config)
```